# AngularJS - cleanup the whole application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, performance, resource-cleanup

In Angularjs, I keep lot of data in my services so that the server calls can be reduced and the data can be picked from local variables. This leads to data being persisted in the application till user refresh screen or close the tab. This is hazard to both security and performance as lot of data is kept in browser memory.

I want to clean up all the services on certain event (like logout) so that the cached data is cleaned up from the browser memory.

Note: I do not want to refresh the screen (window.location.reload) and I have lot of services in my application already. So need some solution with minimum effort.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately javascript doesn't provide any way to manually manage processs such as [garbage collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Gestione_della_Memoria), ecc...

Because you are in an AngularJS app neither the browser-reloading can help you.

there is just one thing that you can do in order to have a best memory management, try to reduce all variables to primitive values when you don't need them anymore.

Keep in mind, javascript clears memory when automatically some variable loses references, for example, variables defined in child scopes are destroyed when the function calls ends.

Comment: Angular services are Singleton and remains in the memory. The major intent is to clear those.

Comment: You cannot destroy services, 
you should use the factory recipe in order to have **lazy loaded** services but you cannot destroy them! Only Scopes can be destroyed!